# Logistic Regression Bigram Text Classification w/ Patsy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, patsy

I'm working on upgrading a LogisticRegression text classification from single word features to bigrams (two word features). However when I include the two word feature in the formula sent to patsy.dmatrices, I receive the following error...

```
y, X = dmatrices("is_host ~ dedicated + hosting + dedicated hosting", df, return_type="dataframe")

  File "<string>", line 1
    dedicated hosting
                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I've looked around online for any examples on how to approach this and haven't found anything. I tried throwing a few different syntax options at the formula and none seem to work.

```
"is_host ~ dedicated + hosting + {dedicated hosting}"
"is_host ~ dedicated + hosting + (dedicated hosting)"
"is_host ~ dedicated + hosting + [dedicated hosting]"
```

What is the proper way to include multi-word features in the formula passed to dmatricies?

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
y, X = dmatrices("is_host ~ dedicated + hosting + Q('dedicated hosting')", df, return_type="dataframe")
```

[`Q` is short for quote](https://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builtins-reference.html#patsy.builtins.Q).